# Canvas Drawing and Performance - 3D Z Buffer

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d

So I'm creating a 3d engine for the javascript canvas, but when I try to draw even simple things like triangles pixel-by-pixel the program's frame rate goes down to like 1fps. I know the ctx.beginPath and ctx.fill to create a triangle are much faster, but why? I've tried using both putImageData and fillRect, but neither perform as well as the ctx.fill(). What could it be doing that I can't?

The reason why I can't use something like ctx.beginPath is because I need to execute a very basic function for every pixel that checks if it has already been draw closer to the viewer. If you've done something like a Z-buffer for the canvas, please help! Thanks.